# How to download and save mp3s

Tags: mp3

I'd like to save this mp3:

> http://www.nhk.or.jp/lesson/english/lesson1.mp3

Is there any way to do this instead of it playing in the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what browser you have, just right-click that link you just made and do "Save linked content as..." or whatever it is called in your browser.

If you are using linux you can open a console window and do

```
wget http://www.nhk.or.jp/lesson/english/lesson1.mp3
```

Comment: not to be nasty but if you know how to use linux and a shell, you have already figured out saving files :)

Comment: @bryan: Not necessarily...there a lot of people out there who figured out how to install Linux but still have no clue about anything.

Comment: installing linux, yes, being familiar with the shell and where to find files created/edited from the shell...i don't think so.

Comment: @bryan: Yeah, I know. Just figured I could throw it in there :p

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the link you provided, click "Save Link As..." and save it where you want it.

Some browsers call it (Save Target As...).

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the link. Select "Save Link As...". Choose a destination

Answer (score 0):

Download your desired MP3 songs from your browser. But I don't know if you want to seek for a downloader to download MP3 songs with ease and free since I can't easily download songs from across the web free. If you are with me, a free MP3 downloader is recommended for you. Just like me, I can use Any MP3 Downloader to download a lot of songs. It's really speedy.

http://download.cnet.com/Any-MP3-Downloader/3000-2141_4-76171793.html

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choice: (WINDOWS)

- Using a DownloadManager which shows a pop up each time a music or video is being streamed in a page and lets you download it.
- Using VideoDownloadHelper Firefox plugin (I dont know if it has an alternative forothers or not).